# Какое расширение необходимо в PHP для использования  idn_to_ascii()?

Tags: apache, php

Какое расширение необходимо в PHP для использования  idn_to_ascii()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php5-intl
```

Установка

```
sudo aptitude install php5-intl
```

Comment: А как его поставить?

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php

PECL intl >= 1.0.2, PECL idn >= 0.1

php5-idn резолвится в php5-intl

Answer (score 0):

Для Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS и выше. Правильный пакет для инсталляции

```
aptitude install php-intl
```